# remove facebook send button's background color

Tags: facebook, button, send, background-color

I'm using facebook Send button on my website. Since a few days, this button has a background color set to white, which is really ugly on my website. I'm also using the Like button, working fine.

Here is an example: ***

The background color is set in the body tag of the iframe, so I dont have access to it...
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

you can try setting colorscheme='dark' if you are using the XFBML code or add &colorscheme=dark to the end of the facebook URL in the iframe src attribute.

Using CSS will not work here since the content is being loaded in an iframe...

Comment: The colorscheme attribute is to alter the color of the button himself. In my case, the default colorscheme="light" is perfectly fine. What I need is to modify the background color of this iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Have you guys tried out using allowTransparency="true" on the iframe tag?

Answer (score 0):

colorscheme changes the button color and also puts a black background on the pop-up, but the white button background remains. I tried setting the fb:send element's width to the button width (about 53px) but the pop-up is a child of that element and gets cut off with that width.

I don't see a solution to it myself. In my project, I was going to put the button on top of an image background but instead I'll have to insert it in a white region below the image.

Comment: i couldnt find a solution, so i went around it. i completely deleted the <fb:send> button, and instead setted the "send=true" attribute in <fb:like>. then the send button appears nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

First, add an #id to your FB code (I use myself a span instead of a div):

```
<span id="fboverlay" class="fb-like" data-href="YOURFACEBOOKADDRESS" data-width="300" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></span>
```

You can leave your code just as it is, **just add that *id="fboverlay"*** over there.

Then edit your css and add:

```
#fboverlay {
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gayscale(100%);
}
```

And that's it.

Shurelly it's using CSS3, therefore it's not 100% compatible (specially with old browsers), you know how it is...